# Flutter: New screen called after await gets stuck

Tags: flutter

I'm using the barcode_scan library. After scanning a barcode, I call Navigator to push a new screen, and the new screen gets stuck. Here you have a [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CtKEJ.jpg) so you can see it.

This is my code:

```
Future scan() async {
try {
  String barcode = await BarcodeScanner.scan();
  Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/restaurant_menu_screen_2');
  ...
```

Comment: What version of flutter are you on?  This should be fixed on master - if it is not please comment on the bug

Comment: I was using the beta branch, I switched to master and it works. Thanks @JonahWilliams

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround here: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/13818

```
  Future scan() async {
    try {
      String barcode = await BarcodeScanner.scan();
      await new Future.delayed(new Duration(milliseconds: 100)); // Add this line      
      Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/restaurant_menu_screen_2');
      ...
```